# Maven - Manipulating files packaged inside WAR during build

Tags: java, maven, jar, properties, war

I currently have many projects, A and B. A is a Spring Boot web-app running on the embedded Tomcat, and depends on the B JAR as follows:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
     <artifactId>B<artifactId>
</dependency>
```

packaged within artifact B is a configuration/properties file, as such

File *propsB.properties*

```
my.property={property.set.by.A}
```

the value of `my.property` is different based on who is pulling in the B JAR dependency, in this case A is pulling it in but there are dozens of other projects depending on it, so hardcoding the value is not easily doable. This is just a tiny example of the situation, but there are hundreds of these properties and files, and many are being used by external frameworks/libraries that cannot resolve property placeholders to system properties (for example) at run time. The property placeholders need to be rewritten in the properties files at runtime (the placeholders are resolved).

My goal is to be able to at runtime specify what all of the property-placeholders should be replaced with. Unpacking the WAR, rewriting the properties files with resolved placeholders is not a great solution, so I am searching for alternatives as I cannot think of any.

The only other solution I can think of is to have all of the properties be in their own JAR file that B depends on, which will then be unpacked at runtime, properties will be resolved, and that will be used.

Comment: Put properties of module A inside module B is not good practice. What is your question? Can you make your problem clearly?

Comment: clarified; I am desiring to be able to specify with what the property placeholders should be replaced with at runtime, and these resolved placeholders have to be written back to the properties files (propsB.properties in this case) so when they are picked up by whatever framework/library uses them they will be resolved.

Comment: You know about spring boot profiles ? Which can be given on runtime?